# What does "glared scarily" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

After searching about "glared scarily" meaning which is not stated directly and/or explicitly, I came up with two possible, yet ambiguous, meanings, either it means (which still may be wrong):

1- Looked at someone angrily or fiercely. (glared frighteningly)

2- Looked at someone for a short while. (got a glimpse)

It carries those two meanings in *Sir Gawain and the Green Knight* book which has stated [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=SVd5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT92&lpg=PT92&dq=glared+scarily+meaning&source=bl&ots=1MoEPlfSvU&sig=ACfU3U3Kr88SV5hzwmZ0o4BJ1dFxKPENrg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGoYr29YjjAhWF-6QKHWJzCdgQ6AEwDXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=glared%20scarily%20meaning&f=false):

> 304: and **scarily glared** round with his red eyes: The word I have translated as 'scarily' is 'runischly' in the original, a word that occurs in several poems [...], but it clearly means 'ferociously'.

I couldn't find the [meaning of 'runischly'](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&source=hp&ei=plMUXcX0OcKFmwXjuKSwAg&q=runischly+meaning&oq=runischly+meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13i10l2j0i22i10i30.1731.3947..4079...0.0..0.355.2186.2-7j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0..33i160.iEGup-Ub5Qo), but I can conclude that it means 'quickly' or something like that.

I think the writer in the quote is certain of it to mean 'ferociously' because of the part '...with his red eyes'; however, the [context](https://www.readlightnovel.org/only-i-level-up/chapter-145) that contains the phrase doesn't have a specific indication of what it could mean exactly:

> X **glared scarily** at Y, before his expression became a lot more serious.

---

So, what does "glared scarily" mean as *a common expression* and *in the context*?

Comment: Why do you think it means "quickly" in _Sir Gawain_? The translator (I think J.R.R. Tolkien of Lord of the Rings fame!) specifically says it means "ferociously." _Scarily_ just means "in a scary way," as if to frighten. _Runischly_ is a word in Middle English (of which Tolkien was a leading expert) and won't be found in modern English dictionaries.

Comment: As they have attempted to translate "scarily", I thought "runischly" and "ferociously" mean two different things, so the writer stated that the original meaning of "scarily" is "runischly", but it would mean "ferociously" though.

Comment: I see. My interpretation of the translator's comment is that _runischly_, based on his research, means _ferociously_, but he chose "scarily" as a more idiomatic (at the time) description. Tolkien did the translation in the 1950s as I recall.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your analysis and this piece of information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Glare", when applied to a person, means "stare fiercely". It never means "look at for a short while".

"Scarily" has its usual meaning, "in a scary or frightening manner". It is an adverb that describes the verb "glare".

The original of Sir Gawain is a 14th century romance, written in Middle English. There are very many words in middle English that are not found in modern English. In fact the original passage goes:

> Þe renk on his rouncé hym ruched in his sadel,
>   **And runischly his rede yȝen he reled aboute,**
>   Bende his bresed broȝez, blycande grene,
>   Wayued his berde for to wayte quo-so wolde ryse.

This is why most readers will depend on a translation. "runischly" doesn't mean "quickly".  As your source says it probably means "ferociously". This reading is based on its use in this and other poems.

You might think "runischly" is related in some way to the verb "to run". It isn't. I don't know the true etymology but there is no reason to think it has any relation to the modern word "to run". The quote illustrates why the poet used "runischly": it is an allitertive phrase  "renk, rounce, runched runishly rede reled". Middle English poems use lots alliteration, and no rhyme.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer! Another reason why I assumed the expression may mean the second meaning is because of Yandex translator which it translated it to mean that.